# How can i make progress bar for livewire function execution in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I Want Make a Progress Bar For My Live Wire Function Progress.
When i Use wire:loading i can just show spinning icon o another text like "uploading ..." , now how can i make progress bar for that ?

I was found it in live wire documentation but not work for show function execution :

```html
<script>
        document.addEventListener('livewire:load',() => {
            let progressSection = document.querySelector('#progressbar'),
                progressBar = progressSection.querySelector('#progress-fill');

            document.addEventListener('livewire-upload-start' , () => {});
            document.addEventListener('livewire-upload-finish' , () => {});
            document.addEventListener('livewire-upload-error' , () => {});
            document.addEventListener('livewire-upload-progress' , (event) => {
                progressSection.style.display = "block";
                console.log(`${event.detail.progress}%`);
                progressBar.style.width = `${event.detail.progress}%`;
            });
        });
        
</script>
```

in the live wire component i was upload file to my ftp server and i want show uploading percentage of file in front end , when i run the upload method.

thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

I had to use Alpine as well for show/hide purpose and plus it binds well with livewire.

Below is an example for uploading resume.

```
<form wire:submit.prevent="uploadResume">

<div x-data="{ isUploading: false, progress: 0 }" 
     x-on:livewire-upload-start="isUploading = true"
     x-on:livewire-upload-finish="isUploading = false" 
     x-on:livewire-upload-error="isUploading = false"
     x-on:livewire-upload-progress="progress = $event.detail.progress">
    
    <input type="file" id="resume" wire:model="resume" aria-label="Resume" />

    <div class="mt-2" x-show="isUploading">
        <progress max="100" x-bind:value="progress"></progress>
    </div>
</div>

</form>
```

```
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;

class Upload extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;

    public function uploadResume()
    {
        // upon form submit, this function till fill your progress bar
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , this is right
but i dont want show progress of file is transfering between user pc and my main host 
i want show progress of file between user pc and my ftp server

Comment: My problem is that the progress bar does not disapper after done uploading.